# Difference between configuration file and script file?

Tags: linux

I want to know exactly the difference between a script file and configuration file.And I came to know to  know from one of my friends that script is a supporting file.Is that true?Please explain that.I got this doubt when i was working with the printer configuration.So Please explain me in detail

Comment: Sometimes, the difference is not exacly clear, since a file containing `key=value` lines could be seen as both; when in doubt, check if the file has the execute permission.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that a script has logic (functions, methods) and is run (interpreted and executed), while a configuration file has only data, and is read (for example by a script).